# Doubts about replacing an LCD display

Tags: lcd

I have a device with a lcd (1602) that needs to be replaced but I'm not sure about finding a compatible one.

The part number is **BC-1602B-SBYA-I-B-A00** and according to the specification [pdf](https://www.peterparts.com/CatalogPages/80/3561.pdf) it has an ST7066 controller which should be compatible with the HD44780 and operates with 5v. But looking at the usual lcds they have their pins on the top side of the pcb, while mine are on the bottom also starting with the pin 14. I don't know if there is reason for that like compability.
[image: BC-1602B-SBYA-I-B-A]

My experience is close to 0. Could I have a problem with the usual displays for arduino?(connected through cables) If not, what features should I look for?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a request for a specific product recommendation. We really don't do that here. Can you make your question more general?

Comment: Hello, it wasn't my intention to ask for a specific lcd, only if I would have problems replacing the one I showing with normal displays that can be found. I think the title was giving the wrong impression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HD44780/ST7066 LCDs of a specific geometry are usually compatible (especially the very common 16x2), but watch out for the orientation and the V0 voltage. (If your circuit doesn't have a contrast adjustment you could add a 10k trim potentiometer.)

So yes, you can most probably make the connection with wires. Or search some more, I've seen 16x2 LCDs with pins on both the top and the bottom side.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have been able to find a few with pins on the bottom. Also there is something about the backlight pins (15-16), they share the same connection with a pair of cement resistors 5W100Ω(parallel), I suppose it is connected to earth and is used as a pull-down resistor?

Comment: 5W resistors are not exactly what I would use for pull-downs. Maybe the backlight is fed from a higher voltage, like 12V?